# Using Jenkins to deploy a war file from dev to QC to live environments

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am new to Jenkins and have got my first build project up and running where it checks my source code out of our SVN repository, then using Maven it packages it to a war file with my naming convention for versions, and deploys it to our development Tomcat server.

Now, our process is that we first deploy to a development tomcat server where the developers perform their testing against that build.

Once they are happy, we want them to go into Jenkins and tell it to send that exact same .war file build to get deployed to a different Quality Control tomcat server where the quality Control team can do their manual tests and sign off that they are happy with the web application.

When the Quality Control team is happy with that .war file build, we want them to be able to go into Jenkins and tell it to send that same .war file to our live environment.

Our developers and Quality Control team have access to the Jenkins server.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this process using Jenkins, SVN, Maven and Tomcat?

Comment: What is QC here? Quality Code department? What kind of tests do you have?Automated, manual? Developers, QC, they all have access to Jenkins?Could you provide more information?

Comment: I have updated the original questions to be more clear. QC is our Quality Control team. For now I am speaking about manual tests that the QC team will perform on our web application. For now, we have no restrictions on who can use Jenkins. So the developers and QC team will have access to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jenkins Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) that does exactly what you want to accomplish:

```
Manual Promotions - You can choose a group of people who can run a promotion manually. 
This gives a way of having a "sign off" within the build system.
For example, a developer might validate a build and approve it for QA testing only when a work product is completed entirely.
Then another promotion can be added for the QA hand off to production.
```

Hope that helps.